# is it possible to attach a string variable in return redirect() in django

Tags: python, django, web, routes, django-urls

I have a situation here where I am creating a record from a view

```
def index(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    order_number = request.POST.get('order_number')
    post_code = request.POST.get('post_code')
    print(order_number)
    print(post_code)
    if order_number and post_code:
        n = page1.objects.create(orderNumber=order_number, postCode=post_code)
        n.save()
        id = n.id
        return redirect("page1:waiting")

return render(request,"page1/index.html")
```

And upon creating the record I am redirecting the user to another page with id.

127.0.0.1/page1/waiting/fb65-io98-.....

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'page1'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="amounts"),
    path('waiting/<str:pk>', views.waitReply, name="waiting"),
]
```

View for Second URL

```
def waitReply(request,pk):
get_amount = page1.objects.get(id=pk)
context = {'get_amount':get_amount}
return render(request, "page1/payment-confirm.html", context)
```

But the problem is how do I attach/generate/get the id in `index` view and send it for the `waitReply` view

I can get the latest ID through `n.id`

Kindly help.

Comment: Try `return redirect("page1:waiting", args=(id))`

Comment: got this error `NoReverseMatch at /page1/
Reverse for 'waiting' with keyword arguments '{'args': UUID('4db21cc9-b348-4e40-bf8e-38eb576e845b')}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['page1/waiting/(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\Z']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reverse with args in HttpResponseRender.
`return HttpResponseRender(reverse('page1:waiting'  args=[id]))`